# How to build a Prestashop 1.6 template?

Tags: php, reactjs, smarty, prestashop

I have to build a webshop for a client with prestashop. I designed the webpage and I have all the static html, but I can't figure out how to customize all the visible modules on f.e. the homepage? I'm used to use php, css, html, etc. But this looks so complex.

I would like to change the structure of the homepage in code in code but there is no .tpl from the homepage? How do I change the structure of pages?

I was also thinking of just using the webservice and creating a React-based webshop with Prestashop as CMS or will that be a bad idea?

Thx!
Greetings

Comment: Prestashop uses a templating engine called Smarty and has a set theme folder structure. I'd advise looking at the folder structure of the default theme you get given with a fresh Prestashop install and replacing the content there with your own. The default theme should ship with several module overrides so you can see how your CSS and .tpl files need to be structured (Usually something like /theme-name/css/modules/module-name/module-name.css). 

Because it's all modular, if you want to change the modules you're loading in, you will have to do this from the Prestashop admin itself.

Comment: Read the documentation: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Theme+development+fundamentals

Comment: I've read the documentation several times. But it wasn't clear to me that you can't edit the structure in code.

Answer (score 1):

To change home page please
- enter back-office
- choose modules -> positions
- found displayHome hook in the list
- there you can see/remove homepage modules

All tpl files are situated [homedir]/modules/[modulename]/*.tpl, [homedir]/modules/[modulename]/views/templates/front/*.tpl or [homedir]/modules/[modulename]/views/templates/admin/*.tpl

and the same in [homedir]/themes/[themename]/modules/[modulename]/*.tpl, [homedir]themes/[themename]/modules/[modulename]/views/templates/front/*.tpl or [homedir]themes/[themename]/modules/[modulename]/views/templates/admin/*.tpl

templates into theme directory have high priority

all css js file both in [homedir]/modules/[modulename]/css and [homedir]/modules/[modulename]/js and theme directory [homedir]themes/[themename]/js/modules/[modulename] or [homedir]themes/[themename]/css/modules/[modulename]

the same high priority for css and js into theme category